# Delphi, FireDAC and custom login sequence

Tags: sql-server, firedac

Using FireDac with SQL Server. For a program where I manage a databasconnection (and thus not always has a database to connect to from the beginning), I want this to happen:

1. The user connects and the OnLogin event is triggered.
2. First I want to try default values/values from a settings file
3. If that fails due to wrong user_name/password I want to show a password dialog
4. Repeat step 3. until login ok or user cancels.

There is some handling of a similar scenario in FireDacs own logindialog, but it seems very complex and the dialog is ugly (I would lika my own!), and also doesn't have a checkbox for "Use OS authentication" that I would need.

Any hints would be great!

/Anders

Comment: Thx Victoria! I think the main problem is: how do I initiate a new connect try? Just trying to open the connection inside the error handler seems wrong..

Comment: Yeah, you're right. My mistake, you cannot "eat" the exception from there. Then just a loop with exception handler. I'll post an example soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to make a [**TFDGUIxLoginDialog**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.UI.TFDGUIxLoginDialog) dialog descendant, you can simply write a loop in which you'll be trying to open the connection handling [**EFDDBEngineException**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException) exception, and asking its [**Kind**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.EFDDBEngineException.Kind) for [**ekUserPwdInvalid**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.TFDCommandExceptionKind) (optionally [**ekUserPwdExpired**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.TFDCommandExceptionKind), or [**ekUserPwdWillExpire**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Stan.Error.TFDCommandExceptionKind) when you need to). Without the [**OnLogin**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.OnLogin) event handler it can be something like this:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  LoginDialog: TMyLoginDialog;
begin
  { ← assign parameters from config file here }
  while True do
  try
    FDConnection.Open; { ← try to connect }
  except
    on E: EFDDBEngineException do
      case E.Kind of
        ekUserPwdInvalid: { ← here you can show your login dialog }
        begin
          LoginDialog := TMyLoginDialog.Create(nil);
          try
            if LoginDialog.ShowModal = mrOk then
            begin
              { ← assign parameters from login dialog here }
            end
            else
              raise; { ← user cancelled login dialog }
          finally
            LoginDialog.Free;
          end;
        end;
        ekUserPwdExpired: { here you can show password change dialog };
        ekUserPwdWillExpire: { here you can optionally show password change dialog };
      else
        raise;
      end;
    else
      raise;
  end;
end;
```

The [**OnError**](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomConnection.OnError) event is no good for this task because there's no way to eat the exception from there. If you release the exception object there (to pretend login was successful and let the engine fail on something else for reconnect attempt), you may get unpredicted behavior (so as when you modify the exception object in a *bad way*).

Comment: This looks fine. I have som trouble though: I would prefer to not use a special procedure to connect, rather I would react on tries from outside, because I don't know the exact places where a connection is needed. But I guess I can actually use the OnError - note that the exception object in the parameters is declared with var, so you can actually free the object, and if you like create a new... I will investigate this and see if I can combine it to something useful.

Comment: I've rolled back to my previous version as I have checked that if you release the exception from `OnError` event handler (eat the exception), you may get unpredicted behavior (because some drivers can continue connecting process). Do not use `OnError` event for this purpose is my final advice.

Comment: I guess you are right: you should not just free the exception. But the help says "You can handle OnError to analyze and modify the exception object. You can even create a new exception object and assign it to AException; if you do so, you must free the original exception object." I'll see what I can make out of it...

Comment: If you free the exception, you fool the connection process (it will move on thinking that login succeeded). If you let **an** exception raise, the connection loop will break (there's an _endless_ loop that loops until the client connects, or **an** exception is raised). Reconnect from that event handler you cannot (because connecting is _in progress_). So what else do you want to come up with?

Comment: Well, just reclassify the exception, but of course that is not essential to the problem. I rest my case...